# Global sections tensoring with different ideal sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a nonsingular smooth projective variety of dimension $n$. Let $A$ be an ample divisor and $N$ be an integer sufficiently large. Let $Y$ be a closed subvariety of codimension$\geq 2$, its corresponding ideal sheaf $I_Y$; let $Z \subset Y$ be a closed subvariety such that codim$Z >$ codim$Y$ and its cooresponding ideal sheaf $I_Z$.

I want to compute the dimension of global sections like

dim$(H^0(X,\mathcal{O}(NA) \otimes I_Y^s \otimes I_Z^r))$

for some $s,r$ fixed integers. By taking $N$ large enough, we assume that $H^0$ is non-empty.

Well, if there is just one ideal sheaf, like $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}(NA) \otimes I_Y^s)$, I can do blow-up along $Y$, get an exceptional divisor and use projection formula to express it as an intersection number or something. If $Y,Z$ are like disjoint subvarieties, I can do the same trick but blow-up 2 times along different subvarieties.

But in this case, I am not quite sure if I blow-up along $Y$ first then $Z$ (or $Z$ first then $Y$) is legal?

Or is there a better way to apply Riemann-Roch other than blowing up? (that is to say I don't know how to find the Chern characters of such sheaves).

Anything is helpful.Thanks.

Comment: This is a difficult computation in general. How explicit do you want the formula to be? Would you be happy to be able to compute only Euler characteristics?

Comment: @DamianRössler Of course it is better than nothing! Asymptotic formula is not good enough since it is basically just the $NA$ contribution.